# Killing a thread when MVar is garbage collected

Tags: haskell, concurrency, garbage-collection

I have a worker thread which reads data repeatedly from an MVar and performs some useful work on that. After a while, the rest of the program forgets about that worker thread, which means that it will wait on an empty MVar and become very lonely. My question is:

> Will the MVar be garbage collected if threads no longer write to it, for instance because they all wait for it?
>   Will garbage collection kill the waiting threads?
>   If neither, can I somehow indicate to the compiler that the MVar should be garbage collected and the thread be killed?

**EDIT:** I should probably clarify the purpose of my question. I don't desire general protection against deadlocks; instead, what I would like to do is to tie the life of the worker thread to life of a value (as in: dead values are claimed by garbage collection). In other words, the worker thread is a resource that I would like to free not by hand, but when a certain value (the MVar or a derivative) is garbage collected.

Here an example program that demonstrates what I have in mind

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.MVar

main = do
    something
    -- the thread forked in  something  can  be killed here
    -- because the  MVar  used for communication is no longer in scope
    etc

something = do
    v <- newEmptyMVar
    forkIO $ forever $ work =<< takeMVar v
    putMVar v "Haskell"
    putMVar v "42"
```

In other words, I want the thread to be killed when I can no longer communicate with it, i.e. when the MVar used for communication is no longer in scope. How to do that?

Comment: Could using a weak reference to the MVar work here?

Comment: @JohnL: Indeed, but what if the thread limits the time it waits for the MVar and periodically checks whether the weak pointer is still alive? (The weak pointer probably has to point to another value, one that goes out of scope simultaneously with the MVar.) Ideally, the period should be given by the frequency of garbage collection.

Comment: @HeinrichApfelmus: my first edit basically does this in one way.  You've suggested another approach that is probably better: spawn another thread to raise an async exception in the blocked thread, interrupting the reading and forcing it to re-read from the weak pointer.  I'll try to work out some code later today.  But still, this seems like a lot of work, using notoriously tricky parts of the language, for something that's easily solved with dons' technique.

Comment: @JohnL: I tested the weak MVar on ghc7.4.1 and it worked for me without needing an async timeout. Code below.

Comment: @ChrisKuklewicz Every so often, a thread arises in which I mostly spread mis-information.  This is one of those threads.  I've deleted most of what I wrote; the only part I think I got correct was that, by the weakref documentation, your code is expected to work (as it does).  Shutting up now...

Comment: @JohnL: you were not wrong about the use of 'addMVarFinalizer', that association will prevent garbage collection.  I discovered the 'mkWeakPtr' trick below mainly by accident -- I did not see why it worked until later.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It will just work: when the `MVar` is only reachable by the thread that is blocked on it, then the thread is sent the `BlockedIndefinitelyOnMVar` exception, which will normally cause it to die silently (the default exception handler for a thread ignores this exception).

BTW, for doing some cleanup when the thread dies, you'll want to use `forkFinally` (which I [just added](https://github.com/ghc/packages-base/commit/40d1be115d2a5a409e9b747c347cd909a9607c42) to `Control.Concurrent`).

Comment: Great! I take it that I can still catch the `BlockedIndefinitelyOnMVar` exception in the thread?

Comment: Sure, `BlockedIndefinitelyOnMVar` is just an ordinary exception.

Comment: Is this true in the case that an MVar is reachable from multiple threads, but they're all blocked on it?  Also, from a GC perspective, does this mean that when a TSO is blocked on an MVar, it's removed from the live set and is only reachable via the MVar?

Answer (score 22):

If you're lucky, you'll get a ["BlockedIndefinitelyOnMVar"](http://blog.ezyang.com/2011/07/blockedindefinitelyonmvar/), indicating that you're waiting on an MVar  that no thread will ever write to.

But, to quote Ed Yang,

> GHC only knows that a thread can be considered garbage if there are no
>   references to the thread. Who is holding a reference to the thread?
>   The MVar, as the thread is blocking on this data structure and has
>   added itself to the blocking list of this. Who is keeping the MVar
>   alive? Why, our closure that contains a call to takeMVar. So the
>   thread stays.
>
> without a bit of work (which would be, by the way, quite interesting to see), BlockedIndefinitelyOnMVar is not an obviously useful mechanism for giving your Haskell programs deadlock protection.

GHC just can't solve the problem in general of knowing whether your thread will make progress.

A better approach would be to explicitly terminate threads by sending them a `Done` message. E.g. just lift your message type into an optional value that also includes an end-of-message value:

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.MVar
import Control.Monad
import Control.Exception
import Prelude hiding (catch)

main = do
    something

    threadDelay (10 * 10^6)
    print "Still here"

something = do
    v <- newEmptyMVar
    forkIO $
        finally
            (let go = do x <- takeMVar v
                         case x of
                            Nothing -> return ()
                            Just v  -> print v >> go
             in go)
            (print "Done!")

    putMVar v $ Just "Haskell"
    putMVar v $ Just "42"

    putMVar v Nothing
```

and we get the correct clean up:

```
$ ./A
"Haskell"
"42"
"Done!"
"Still here"
```

Comment: Ah, I see, so I have to kill the thread by hand. (I can throw an exception to it as well). I should probably clarify what I really wanted to do, though. Namely, I wanted to tie the life of the thread to the life of value, i.e. consider the thread as a resource that is freed upon garbage collection of the MVar, just like garbage collection of the result of `readFile` should close the file.

Answer (score 11):

I tested the simple weak MVar and it did get finalized and killed.  The code is:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Exception
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.MVar
import System.Mem(performGC)
import System.Mem.Weak

dologger :: MVar String -> IO ()
dologger mv = do
  tid <- myThreadId
  weak <- mkWeakPtr mv (Just (putStrLn "X" >> killThread tid))
  logger weak

logger :: Weak (MVar String) -> IO ()
logger weak = act where
  act = do
    v <- deRefWeak weak
    case v of
      Just mv -> do
       a <- try (takeMVar mv) :: IO (Either SomeException String)
       print a
       either (\_ -> return ()) (\_ -> act) a
      Nothing -> return ()

play mv = act where
  act = do
    c <- getLine
    if c=="quit" then return ()
       else putMVar mv c >> act

doplay mv = do
  forkIO (dologger mv)
  play mv

main = do
  putStrLn "Enter a string to escape, or quit to exit"
  mv <- newEmptyMVar
  doplay mv

  putStrLn "*"
  performGC
  putStrLn "*"
  yield
  putStrLn "*"
  threadDelay (10^6)
  putStrLn "*"
```

The session with the program was:

```
(chrisk)-(/tmp)
(! 624)-> ghc -threaded -rtsopts --make weak2.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( weak2.hs, weak2.o )
Linking weak2 ...

(chrisk)-(/tmp)
(! 625)-> ./weak2 +RTS -N4 -RTS
Enter a string to escape, or quit to exit
This is a test
Right "This is a test"
Tab Tab
Right "Tab\tTab"
quit
*
*
X
*
Left thread killed
*
```

So blocking on takeMVar did *not* keep the MVar alive on ghc-7.4.1 despite expectations.

Comment: Nice! So, your code clearly demonstrates that the finalizer is run while the thread is still waiting for the MVar. It appears that `takeMVar` will deconstruct the internal representation of the MVar to the point that the "outer hull" can be garbage collected. A similar effect can probably be achieved for any data structure by using `data Lazy a = Lazy  a` and putting a finalizer on `Lazy (MVar String)` instead of directly on `MVar String`.

Comment: Yeah, I also figured it out.  The difference is between addMVarFinalizer and addFinalizer.  The last item put into the MVar may be irretrievable, but I think this is okay for this usage.

Answer (score 1):

While `BlockedIndefinitelyOnMVar` should work, also consider using [ForeignPointer finalizers](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/FFI#Self-Deallocating_Pointers). The normal role of those is to delete C structures that are no longer accessible in Haskell. However, you can attach any IO finalizer to them.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you can't attach any IO action to them, it has to be a C finalizer. Is that still true?

Comment: "a pointer to a Haskell function created using a wrapper stub declared to produce a FunPtr of the correct type." [Foreign.Ptr](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Foreign-Ptr.html#t%3AFunPtr)

Comment: It's not that easy. http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/ffi-ghc.html